# What is a good book to read about 3D printers?

Tags: printer-building

I've been interested in 3D printing for the past month however, I have noticed that it's sort of a "reserved" topic. Meaning that everyone who talks about it, has already some basic knowledge about the topic. What are some good resources for someone who wants to start learning from zero? My main goal is to acquire enough knowledge in order to build my own 3D printer.

Comment: As it stands, I think this question is too broad for the requirements of this site. I understand the state of not knowing what questions to ask, but this site is designed for more specific questions. Perhaps try rewording your question to outline what resources haven't worked for you and what type of information (specifically) can help you start your adventures in 3D printing. Best regards and welcome!

Comment: I don't understand the want to close everything that doesn't say what specific printer they are using and what the alloy is of the bolt that is driving the filament.  Answers to this question would not only be beneficial to the original poster but many other new people that find the site as well.  The question is easy enough to answer and I'm sure all of us have a few websites that we check daily for information.

Comment: @tjb1 this is a *shopping* question as there are as many good answers as there are books about the topic.

Comment: @Trish This question was asked when the site was only 4 months old and struggling to get started.  The site needed questions then and still needs questions today. What do we gain by closing a 2.5 year old question with 5 answers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can learn a lot just by reading the forums.  I'll just list a few that are quite popular...

[Reprap Forums](http://forums.reprap.org/) - Has a ton of information on DIY printers including build logs and posts dealing with many issues.

[Soliforum](http://www.soliforum.com) - Large user base with lots of information. Not sure what it's standing is now that Solidoodle is gone but I'm sure the forum will stick around.

[SeeMeCNC](http://forum.seemecnc.com/) - Support forum for SeeMeCNC, has a lot of information for Delta printers and also other printers.

There aren't many books that I know of...Make magazine has done a few issues on 3D printing that you could try to obtain.  I'm not sure what your idea of building a printer is, do you want to design your own or follow someone's instructions and put one together?  Designing one would require some basic hardware and engineering knowledge.

All that said, the best learning experience would be buying a kit and learning as you go.  You'll never read in a book what you will learn from having your own printer.

Answer (score 3):

The resources you have at your fingertips are going to be more up-to-date than anything you'll find in a paper/published book. Use this amazing thing called the internet and read everything you can find. Use Google or your favorite search engine using appropriate terms. I'd suggest, based on your overly broad question, that you use "build your own 3d printer" as a starting point.

You'll find that [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/) is one useful resource as well as [MakerShed](http://www.makershed.com/) for additional material. You will find a very large source of helpful information at [3dprintboard.com](http://3dprintboard.com/) simply by reading others' posts there and at other forums as well.

There is quite a bit to absorb and understand but with the internet at your fingertips, you won't be lacking for information.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend **[Design for 3D Printing: Scanning, Creating, Editing, Remixing, and Making in Three Dimensions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1457187361)** by Samuel N. Bernier, Bertier Luyt and Tatiana Reinhard

[image]

It has a lot of tips, tricks and examples.
Good for beginners and experienced users.

Answer (score 1):

ADDITIVE MANUFACTURING TECHNOLOGIES
3D Printing, Rapid Prototyping, and
Direct Digital Manufacturing

Springer

I think its a perfect book. A lot of details to all technologies.
*Beware there is math and physics involved.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to learn about three dimensional printing then "Mastering 3D Printing" by Joan Horvath, published by Apress, would be a good place to start.

It does not provide you the in depth knowledge about all the types of printers or materials but it is good enough to get a newbie like me or you get of the ground.